# how can i open sharepoint library from windows explorer C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to open a sharepoint url (library) in my windows explorer with C #. How can I do it.
I tried with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("explorer.exe", @ "http: \ ...") but it does not work. Because it opens with web browser.
Pleease help me, and my apologise for my English.

Comment: The web browser doesn't matter - SharePoint is a *web application*. If you call a web url, the site will open up just like any other. Are you sure you *can* open the library in the first place? Can you see the `Open in Explolrer` button in the library's page?

Comment: yes, but i want open it in windows esplores with c#

Comment: Copy the *UNC* then and use it just like any other, eg `Process.Start(@"\\myservers\\....\mylibrary")`. You can find the UNC in the properties tab of the library or any folder in it in Explorer.

Comment: I do it, but it keep opening in a web browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint uses WebDAV to allow Windows to treat document libraries like network shares. This requires the `Web Folders` feature on all clients, and the WebClient service must be running. If any of these things isn't working, you can't access the document library from Explorer.

If you can open the library in Windows Explorer, you can treat its path like any other UNC path and write eg: `Process.Start(@"\\myServer\...\mylibrary")` to open it.

You can get the UNC path if you open the library in Windows Explorer, right click on it and select `Properties`.

Another option is to add the UNC path *or* URL as a network drive to Windows and access the library by the drive name.

Comment: sorry but, what is UNC

Comment: Thank you, It has been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, "`invoke-item \\site.test.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\siteID\Documents`" will work. same can be done through .net code.

please find out the path to be used by adding "SharePoint library" once to windows explorer favorites menu by using these steps.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2629108/how-to-use-the-open-with-explorer-command-to-troubleshoot-issues-in-sh

Comment: This works for the wrong reasons. SharePoint uses WebDAV to allow Windows to treat libraries like network shares. This requires the `Web Folders` feature on all clients. If either is missing, you can't open the library as a folder. PowerShell has nothing to do with it